# How would I set the value of currentIndex to 0 for every calculation

Tags: javascript

How do I go about changing the Value of currentIndex to always equal 0.

The price from (CRANK1 + CRANK2) + (DRANK1 + DRANK2) should be (0 + selected amount), but its adding (selected amount + selected amount)

Any help is appreciated, thank you.
 POST IS MOSTLY CODE NEED TEXT POST IS MOSTLY CODE NEED TEXT POST IS MOSTLY CODE NEED TEXT

```
var current_division,
    desired_division;


var prices = [
00,09,09,09,09,
12,12,14,14,14,
17,17,17,17,19,
23,24,25,28,28,
35,40,50,65,85,
120,00,00,00,00
];


function getCurrentIndex() {
  return (+document.getElementById("CRANK1").value + 
    +document.getElementById("CRANK2").value);

}

function getDesiredIndex() {
  return (+document.getElementById("DRANK1").value + 
    +document.getElementById("DRANK2").value);
}


function total() {
  var currentIndex = getCurrentIndex();
  var desiredIndex = getDesiredIndex();

   if (desiredIndex < currentIndex) {
    document.getElementById('prices').value = "You can't rank backwards";
    return;
  }

  var accumulatedPrice = 0;
  for(var i = currentIndex; i <= desiredIndex; i++) {
    accumulatedPrice += prices[i];
  }

  document.getElementById('prices').value = accumulatedPrice;
  document.getElementById("prices").readOnly = true;

}

document.getElementById('divboost').addEventListener('change', function() {
  total();
})
```

HTML

```
  <form id="divboost" name="priceCalc" action="">
    <br/>
    <select id="CRANK1"> Current Rank
          <option value="0">Bronze</option>
          <option value="5">Silver</option>
          <option value="10">Gold</option>
          <option value="15">Platinum</option>
          <option value="20">Diamond</option>
      </select>
    <br>
    <br/>
    <select id="CRANK2"> Current Divison
          <option value="0">Division 5</option>
          <option value="1">Division 4</option>
          <option value="2">Division 3</option>
          <option value="3">Division 2</option>
          <option value="4">Division 1</option>
      </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <select id="DRANK1"> Desired Rank
          <option value="0">Bronze</option>
          <option value="5">Silver</option>
          <option value="10">Gold</option>
          <option value="15">Platinum</option>
          <option value="20">Diamond</option>
          <option value="25">Master</option>
      </select>
    <br>
    <br/>
    <select id="DRANK2"> Desired Divison
          <option value="0">Division 5</option>
          <option value="1">Division 4</option>
          <option value="2">Division 3</option>
          <option value="3">Division 2</option>
          <option value="4">Division 1</option>
      </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    € <input type="text" id="prices">
    <br/>
    <br>
  </form>
```

Comment: You have too many `+` here `(+document.getElementById("CRANK1").value + 
    +document.getElementById("CRANK2").value);`

Comment: can you show us the html part too?

Comment: @Andrew Lohr Added HTML

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you expect, I am having trouble finding the problem in your code.

Comment: @Andrew Lohr I've made a gif to visually show my problem: https://i.gyazo.com/e6263522b32d14edfb3ae548971298f7.mp4 The price should drop to 9 when going from 5 to 4. i'm looking for a solution for the top 2 selects to always equal 0, so its always 0 + the bottom selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around a bit I noticed you do not want to add the first `currentIndex` to your `accumulatedPrice`.

By incrementing `currentIndex` right before the loop you should get the expected behavior you want

```
  var accumulatedPrice = 0;
  currentIndex++;
  for(var i = currentIndex; i <= desiredIndex; i++) {
    accumulatedPrice += prices[i];
  }
```

or you can add 1 to the returned value from your `getCurrentIndex()` function